# Python callback in Bokeh issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I am trying to get a callback function to work in bokeh based on this simple example:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

TOOLS = "tap,reset"
p = figure(title="Some Figure", tools=TOOLS)

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=[[1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 6, 6]],
                y=[[2, 1, 4], [4, 7, 8, 5]], name=['A', 'B']))

pglyph = p.patches('x', 'y', source=source)

def callback(attr, old, new):
    # The index of the selected glyph is : new['1d']['indices'][0]
    print("In callback")
    patch_name =  source.data['name'][new['1d']['indices'][0]]
    print("TapTool callback executed on Patch {}".format(patch_name))

pglyph.data_source.on_change('selected',callback)

curdoc().add_root(column(p))
```

When I load the page and click on a polygon, I do not see the callback getting executed.

What is missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the `selected` attribute value is not changed. The contained object is changed instead, and Bokeh doesn't detect deep changes.

Try replacing the callback function and the next line with:

```py
def callback(attr, old, new):
    print("In callback")
    patch_name = source.data['name'][new[0]]
    print("TapTool callback executed on Patch {}".format(patch_name))


pglyph.data_source.selected.on_change('indices', callback)
```